# leaflet, printing using browserPrint

Tags: javascript, printing, leaflet

I am using Java to create a web map. 
My issue has to do with printing. I was using easyPrint but had problems with map shifting. This was overcome when changed into browserPrint, but now both the active layers and the control layer are not illustrated in the printing outcome, nor shown in the preview.
I have included these in my script, as recommended:

script src="js/leaflet.browser.print.min.js">

L.browserPrint({
  title: 'Print map',
  position: 'bottomleft'
  }).addTo(map);

I don't specify the printLayer as I want the active layers to be printed.
Any ideas??
Thank you!